# Is there any way (e.g. add-on) to show a file list when switching tabs?

Tags: tabs, komodo, komodoedit

I would like to have Komodo Edit display the list of files it will switch to when I switch to another tab via <kbd>Ctrl+Tab</kbd>, as is the case in Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA IDEs.

Is there any way to achieve this, maybe through a hidden setting or an add-on ?

One reason for asking this is because Komodo's tab order is not very intuitive - it does not seem to (fully) be by most recently active tab (e.g. closing tabs changes order of remaining tabs), and it also depends on whether you release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while navigating between the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exist in add-on or prefs form but it's an interesting idea.

What might help you is View > Tabs & Sidebars > Open Files.  You can at least see all your tabs more easily.

The order is based on last active file.  If you like, you can think of it as a list that can have items remove from any where, bottom, middle or top, but can only have items added to the top.  For example:

Open five files, A B C D E, in that order

```
Tab order = E D C B A
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to file C

```
Tab order = C E D B A
```

close file E

```
Tab order = C D B A
```

Hope that's helpful.  That does sound like a cool extension though.

EDIT: The above algorithm breaks if you don't have Edit menu > Preferences > Editor: Tabs: "When I close the current tab, switch to most recent..." enabled.

Comment: Well, it's not very intuitive the way it is. It should be based on last used only but it isn't. When you close a file, it gets mixed up, and switching turns up files you haven't touched for a long time, which is totally unusable.

Comment: Did you enable the preferences I added an Edit about?  It should do exactly what you're asking if you have.

Comment: Of course I have it switch to the most recent tab set, and, it behaves in exactly that weird way I described. It is just a bad implementation. Just try it yourself. And regardless of whether it works, it is still hard to know what tab it will switch to when you tab multiple times.

Comment: I wasn't sure.  You didn't mention having it enabled.  It works as expect for me when I have the option enable.  Either way, I'm dragging you away from the question you asked.  I'm more than will to help try and figure out why Komodo seems to be working incorrectly for you in regards to tab history order but there is no exiting add-on to provide the feature you originally mentioned.  Could be interesting to write when time becomes slightly more abundant :D